# How to define a new global object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi
It is good practice to create one unique global object that wrap the functions and properties inside this object.I look up a lot of sample code and see code like this

```
if(!myglobalObject) myglobalObject ={};
```

However , this code does not work ,I got an error saying 
**ReferenceError: myglobalObject is not defined**
Can anyone shed some light on why I got the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid errors in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, you need to use `var` to define all variables:

```
if (typeof myglobalObject == "undefined") {
    var myglobalObject = {};
}
```

The other alternative is to assign a property to the global object:

```
// The following line gets you a global object in any ECMAScript
// environment, so long as it runs in the global scope. In browsers,
// you could just use window.
var globalObj = this;
if (typeof globalObj.myglobalObject == "undefined") {
    globalObj.myglobalObject = {};
}
```

Comment: Speaking of strict mode, `globalObj` in the second snippet will evaluate to `undefined`... when in strict mode. So `var globalObj = this` (from within global code) might be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof myglobalObject === 'undefined') var myglobalObject = {};
```

Comment: Assignment to an undeclared variable (as you're doing here) will cause an error in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. Use a `var` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

`if (window['myglobalObject'] === undefined) window.myglobalObject = {};`

If you don't want to expose your object from context you can do smth like this:

`var myglobalObject = myglobalObject || {};`